# How do I make this pop-up menu close at any click on the page outside of this html menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This webpage has a navigation menu that functions properly. When you click on the navigation icon, a menu will appear. When you click on the same icon, the navigation menu disappears.

However, it would be nice to make sure that if there is a navigation menu, clicking anywhere outside of it also causes it to disappear.

I don't understand a bit how to do this in js so please help

code html:

```
<ul class="main-nav nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="/index.html">ГЛАВНАЯ</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">НОВОСТИ</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">СТАТЬИ</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ВИДЕО</a></li>
    <li><a href="/onas.html">О НАС </a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, in order to ask the best question, I recommend checking out [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Bind a mousedown or click event handler to the document and check whether the click was done outside your menu or menu toggle button:

```
document.addEventListener('click', e => {

   if( ! e.target.closest('.main-nav, .main-nav-toggle')){
       document.querySelector('.main-nav').style.display = 'none';
   }

});
```

Make sure `display:none` is in sync with your toggling code.